# Unknown checkpoint file in tensorflow model zoo

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, pre-trained-model, tensorflow1.15

I want to know the type of checkpoint files in [TPU Object Detection and Segmentation Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/official/detection/MODEL_ZOO.md) because it has no suffix.

checkpoint file in tensorflow has foramat like this:

checkpoint
.data
.index

Thanke you all.

Answer (score 0):

This `model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001` is the `.data` file. Checkpoints are generally saved after each training epoch and the file names are incremented, hence the 0001. The `checkpoint` file is a text file, which you can open in a text editor to confirm it's not your checkpoints. If you are seeing different files try linking directly to those particular models in your post, as the models I noted had these files.

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) is a good backgrounder.

Comment: I opened it and saw this:   checkpoint    model_checkpoint_path: "model.ckpt"  
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt". but there is no `model.ckpt`. just a big file with unknow characters.